# What is the matrix norm in defining the generator of a continuous time Markov chain?

Tags: matrices, functional-analysis, markov-chains

For a continuous time Markov chain with finite state space and Markov transition function $p(t)$, its generator $G$ can be defined entry-wise as
$$
G_{i,j}:=\lim_{t\to 0^+} \frac{p_{i,j}(t) - \delta_{i,j} }{t}, \forall \text{ states }i, j
$$

$G$ can also be defined as
$$G := \frac{dp(t)}{dt} |_{t=0^+}, 
$$
I was wondering what the matrix norm is in defining $\frac{dp(t)}{dt} |_{t=0^+}$ above?

Thanks and regards!

Comment: Wouldn't it not matter, because all matrix norms are equivalent?

Comment: @ChristopherA.Wong: (1) All matrix norms are equivalent in the sense that they induce the same topology. So in the definition of derivative of a matrix-valued function, the convergence can be wrt any matrix norm. Is that what you mean? (2) How do you show that the derivative defined entry-wise, and the derivative defined wrt a matrix norm are equivalent?